# Textjoin with adjacent headers and rows with a twist

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to perform a `Textjoin()` when the cell is filled in a row to get the adjacent row header:
I have a formula that works without looking at the blanks.

The desired output would be:

***example desired output***:
[image]

I have a formula that works without looking at the blanks, what I need is when there is a blank cell the adjacent header is ignored.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? [See here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know,I was too late, but I came here with another approach..

[image: Result]

=TEXTJOIN(" ",,IF(ISBLANK(A2:C2),"",$A$1:$C$1&":"&A2:C2))

also

=TEXTJOIN(" ",,IF(A2:C2=0,"",$A$1:$C$1&":"&A2:C2))

Answer (score 2):

Try the following formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTER($A$1:$C$1,A2:C2<>"")&":"&FILTER(A2:C2,A2:C2<>""))
```

To make it dynamic (automatically spill result) try-

```
=BYROW(A2:C4,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTER(A1:C1,x<>"")&":"&FILTER(x,x<>""))))
```

[image]